# How do I share resolve data between Angular ui-route's parent/child states when on different views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's what I have. I need `categories` to be available at `HomeController` and `NavbarController`.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('master', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'navbar@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/navbar.default.html',
                    controller: 'NavbarController as nb',
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                categories: function(Category) {
                    return Category.getList({ depth: 0 });
                },
            }
        })

        .state('home', {
            parent: 'master',
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'main@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController as hc',
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                deals: function(Deal) {
                    return Deal.getList();
                },
            }
        });
```

Comment: So you don't have access to NavbarController from HomeController?

Comment: would it work to pass it to a service, and then inject that service into both controllers? that's what I typically do if I need something to be accessed on multiple controllers, though I don't have experience with using the resolves in $stateprovider like you have

Comment: @LukeSchunk How would you implement that if you want the promises to be resolved and the controlled only called after that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies)

> Child states will inherit resolved dependencies from parent state(s), which they can overwrite. You can then inject resolved dependencies into the controllers and resolve functions of child states.

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
  resolve:{
     resA:  function(){
        return {'value': 'A'};
     }
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA){
      $scope.resA = resA.value;
  }})
 .state('parent.child', {
  resolve:{
     resB: function(resA){
        return {'value': resA.value + 'B'};
     }
  },
   controller: function($scope, resA, resB){
      $scope.resA2 = resA.value;
      $scope.resB = resB.value;
  }
```

It also states:

> The resolve keyword MUST be relative to state not views (in case you use multiple views).
>   The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the children.

Comment: It looks like the issue comes tied to the fact that I'm using two different views (`navbar` and `main`). From the docs: "It is entirely possible that you have nested states whose templates populate ui-views at various non-nested locations within your site. In this scenario you cannot expect to access the scope variables of parent state views within the views of children states."

Comment: Correct. Maybe you could instead share custom data points instead custom data (obtained from a service) could be an option to try.

Comment: I could. How will that work? I basically need the resolves to load before both controllers execute. Could you post an example?